# Copying datasets feature vs BigQuery Transfer service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Our source is bigquery datasets. We would like to copy datasets across regions.

1. What is the difference between Copying datasets feature vs BigQuery Transfer service?
2. Per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#pricing?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=Unpaidsocial&utm_campaign=wil-20200916-bigquery-pricing-info) Copying datasets is Beta Feature and it is free , Does this mean even the data extraction from Source is free or is it only the Egress charges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "real" difference. In fact, BigQuery Data Transfer Service is used for more sources than BigQuery dataset only.

For BigQuery, the copy dataset is a feature of BigQuery data transfert. To convince yourself, you can try a copy dataset without the BigQUery data transfer service API activated, and you can't! The activation is mandatory.

About the pricing, you have to pay the egress cost. But I'm currently in discussion with Google Cloud because it's not clear. Google Cloud told me the doc is outdated and normally, it's the Cloud Storage egress cost that apply (instead of Compute Engine egress cost).

It makes sense because the copy dataset is simply a wrapper:

- Export the data from a table to Cloud Storage (free operation in BigQuery) in region A
- Copy the export from the region A to a Cloud Storage in region B (here egress should apply)
- BigQuery load job is created from the export in the region B (free operation in BigQuery)

I have no confirmation yet. Especially because the feature is free for now and I don't know if the egress is also free.

Comment: please post an update , if you hear back from Google